# My PHP form will not send to multiple users

Tags: php, forms

Hi I have a php form that works perfectly when it sends an email to one person but when I add another email address it doesn't send an email to either address. I have been looking on php sites but can't see why my form is now refusing to email once the second email address is added.

```
   <?php 
    function isRequestSet( $name ) { 
if ( isset ( $_REQUEST[$name] ) ) { 
    return ( $_REQUEST[$name] != "" ) ;
}
return false;
    }

    $name = "";
     if ( isRequestSet('name' ) ) { 
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    } 
    $number = "";
    if ( isRequestSet('number') ) { 
$number = $_REQUEST['number'];
    }
    $email = "";
    if ( isRequestSet( 'email' ) ) { 
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    }
     $postcode = "";
     if ( isRequestSet('postcode' ) ) { 
$location = $_REQEUST['postcode'];
     }

     $how_did_you_hear_about_us = array();
     if ( isset( $_REQUEST['how_did_you_hear_about_us'] )  ) { 
$how_did_you_hear_about_us = $_REQUEST['how_did_you_hear_about_us']; 
    }

     $message = "";
      if ( isRequestSet('message' ) ) { 
$location = $_REQEUST['message'];
      }
     $apartment_price_range = array();
      if ( isset( $_REQUEST['apartment_price_range'] )  ) { 
$apartment_price_range = $_REQUEST['apartment_price_range']; 
     }

    $url = "";{
$url = $_REQUEST['url'];
}

    $property = "";{
$property = $_REQUEST['property'];
}


    if ( ($name !="") && ($number != "") && ($email != "") && ($isspam !="yes") ) { 
$to = 'name@email.com,name@email2.com';
$from = $to;
$headers =  'From: ' . $to . "\n" .
            'Reply-To: ' . $to . "\n";
$vars = array( 'name' , 'number' , 'email' , 'postcode' , 'message' ) ;
$message = "-----------\n" ;
foreach ( $vars as $v ) { 
    $value = $_REQUEST[$v];
    $message .= "$v:\t$value\n";
}
$message .= "-----------\n" ;
$message .= "\nHow did you hear about apartments?:\n"  ;
foreach ( $how_did_you_hear_about_us as $how_did_you_hear_about_us ) { 

    $message .= "$how_did_you_hear_about_us\n" ; 
}

$message .= "-----------\n" ;
$message .= "\nApartment price range:\n"  ;
foreach ( $apartment_price_range as $apartment_price_range ) { 

    $message .= "$apartment_price_range\n" ; 
}
$subject = "From: $name <$email>";
mail( $to , $subject , $message , $headers,  "-f $from" );
$confirm = true;
//redirect to the 'thank you' page
header("Location:http://website.com/file/thankyou.php");
     } else { 
$confirm = false;
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it is because you use multiple addresses for From and Reply-to fields:

```
$to = 'name@email.com,name@email2.com';
$from = $to;
```

Change it to use either first email or something like your-service-name@you-domain-name.com

Answer (score 0):

Use only one address for From and Reply-To.

```
$from = 'me@my-domain.com';
$headers =  'From: ' . $from . "\n" .
            'Reply-To: ' . $from . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

"In the line below you should break the $to field into an array.

```
mail( $to , $subject , $message , $headers,  "-f $from" );
```

For example

```
$address_array = split(",", $to);

foreach($address_array as $address)
{
mail( $address, $subject , $message , $headers,  "-f $from" );
}
```

This allows for you $to string to contain as many emails as desired.

N.b if you wish to skip the split line just store the $to as an array

```
$to = array("name@email.com","name@email2.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

make your email part into a function.
will much more easier for you to pass the email address.

```
function email_to_user($email_address){
   $to = $email_address;

   <rest of the codes>

}
```

and you can easily pass the email address

```
email_to_user(name1@mail.com);
email_to_user(name2@mail.com);
```